# Decrypt cypherTextBlob using AWS KMS programmatically in Java ? InvalidCiphertextException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, base64, amazon-kms

I am a bit new to cryptography and never used AWS KMS to encrypt data before.
I am using AWS SDK for Java for KMS.
But while trying to encrypt and decrypt using AWS KMS API Operations, I am facing the exception InvalidCiphertextException

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>kms</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.19</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Encrypt part**

```
String encrypt(String plainText){
EncryptRequest encryptRequest = new EncryptRequest().withKeyId(keyId).withPlaintext(plainText);

//calling encrypt function here 
EncryptResult response = kmsClient.encrypt(encryptRequest);
cipherText =  new String(response.getCiphertextBlob().array());
//calling decrypt function here
return decrypt(cipherText);
}
```

**Decrypt part in decrypt method**

```
public String decrypt(String cipherText){
ByteBuffer cyphertextBlob = ByteBuffer.wrap(cipherText.getBytes());

//Point 1: Exception is thrown at this point while calling decrypt operation API.

DecryptRequest request = new DecryptRequest().withKeyId(keyId).withCiphertextBlob(cyphertextBlob);
}
```

The problem is I get the following error at the point of making the api call (Point 1)

`com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.InvalidCiphertextException: null (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidCiphertextException; Request ID: 45720b33-3637-490a-8c6a-d7491ccadf94; Proxy: null)`

InvalidCiphertextException. While going through AWS documents, here are the points I understood,

- The encryption context is cryptographically tied to the cypher text so **InvalidCiphertextException** is thrown if we don't provide the encryptionContext in decrypt operation. But I am not providing encryptionContext while encrypting.
- I also tried using withEncryptionContext(null) while preparing the Encryption and Decryption Context.

Do I need to do any other step to manipulate/transform the cipher text before using decryption request ?

can anyone help with this please ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to update here in case anyone got stock at this problem.

While debugging found out that, the capacity and the limit of *ByteBuffer* object obtained using the get methods of the KMS response was different than the default capacity and limit while creating one from the cipherText in the *decrypt* method. So this caused the exception.

Answer (score -1):

I am also faced same problem.Then i realised i am converting to String directly. But we can  Store as ByteBuffer. so i did it and retrived it. the problem is resolved.

```
  EncryptResponse response = kmsClient.encrypt(encryptRequest);

  CreateSecretRequest createSecretRequest = CreateSecretRequest.builder()
      .name("dev/encrypte******")
      .kmsKeyId(config.getArn())
      .secretBinary(response.ciphertextBlob())
      .build();

  -- --Decryption-- --

  DecryptResponse decryptResponse = kmsClient.decrypt(decryptRequest);
  String decrypted = new String(decryptResponse.plaintext().asByteArray());
```